# Woocommerce shipping core tweak

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any simple way to add a hook, so if customer add one product to their cart containing `tech` in the product title and another containing `game` in the product title to apply 50% discount on shipping for the product containing `tech` in the title?

I am using the standard WordPress (woocommerce) shipping core functions set to the following:

`No shipping class` price formula (containing most of my items containing `tech` in the product title): **10 + ( 9.99 * [qty] )**

`Game shipping class` price formula (containing most of my items containing `game` in the product title): **20 + ( 19.99 * [qty] )**

Both works as they should.

One `tech` item shipping price is 19.99 and every additional item is 9.99

One `game` item shipping price is 39.99 and every additional item is 19.99

However, when I add one (or more) `tech` and one (or more) `game` items in my cart, it should deduct 50% of the least expensive shipping similar to what `no class` or `game class` shipping method currently do but combine them somehow.

Currently when I add one `tech` and `game` item to my cart then my shipping is 59.98 and in fact it should be 49.98

So, basically I have to edit the `Calculation Type` method in the woocommerce's shipping function. It's set to `Per class: Charge shipping for each shipping class individually`.

It should be an easy tweak, however I am not sure where to start. Any suggestion or an idea would be really helpful.

Comment: This can't be done through formulas and require some code customization using `woocommerce_package_rates`filter hook, like in [those threads using this filter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_package_rates) or [those other ones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_package_rates)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - Thank you for pointing out the correct filter hook, but it still seems unclear to me. Is there any code example of something similar or already existing plugin you may know? Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: No sorry I don't have any ready to go example code, so you need to try that yourself, targeting "flat_rate" shipping method id and ( on cart items) each related shipping class where you are using formulas, to alter shipping cost. So this is not something simple.